# Cannot trigger a tooltip using bootstrap gives an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a **tooltip** to show if `mouse is over` a truncated text.
But I get the following **error**

> Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'options'.

I've also tried to call it when ellipsis is active, doesn't work as well. What is wrong here? How can it all be done?

**html:**

```
<div>
    <label class='form-control' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='something'>truncated text</label>
<div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".form-control", function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (this.offsetWidth > this.scrollWidth) {
         $this.tooltip('options', 'show');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer http://codepen.io/avnish002/pen/rxjWzE

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".iffyTip", function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')) {
         $this.tooltip({
             title: $this.text(),
             placement: "top"
         });
         $this.tooltip('show');
     }
 });
$('.hideText').css('width',$('.hideText').parent().width());
```

Comment: Doesn't go inside the if statemet anyway regardless of whether ellipsis works or not

Comment: if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth)  this checks if the element has ellipsis or not to decide whether to show the tooltip or not. What is the issue?

Comment: Can you upvote and accept my ans if it did work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [tooltip docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips), use `.tooltip('show')` only like,

```
$this.tooltip('show');
```

Your code should be like,

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".form-control", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (this.offsetWidth > this.scrollWidth) {
        $this.tooltip('show');
    } else {
        $this.tooltip('hide');
    }
});
```

Snippet,

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".form-control", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.tooltip('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
<label class='form-control' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='something'>truncated text</label>
<div>
```

Comment: I get this - Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'

Comment: It will not cause any error if you have added `data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='something'` in your element. As the selector `data-toggle='tooltip'` automatically initialise it in bootstrap tooltip js.

Comment: And yet it doesn't for some reason. Bootstrap.min is definitely linked.